# HTTP 500 internal server error when getting Comments from Box API v2

Tags: box-api, box, boxapiv2

When I try to make a request to get the comments of a specific file which contains a large number of comments (around 70000), I get a 500 Internal Server Error.

Here is the request that I am sending and the response that is coming back (I have replaced the values of the fileId and token in the request):

```
GET /2.0/files/[my_file_id]/comments?fields=id,message,tagged_message,created_at,item,created_by HTTP/1.1
Host: api.box.com
Authorization: Bearer [my_token]
Accept: application/json
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: CData Data Provider Engine - www.cdata.com - Accepts: gzip
Connection: close
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Server: ATS
Date: Mon, 06 Feb 2017 15:19:30 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Length: 20
Age: 82
Connection: close
```

Is there any reason why I am getting this kind of error?

Comment: Might be that it takes to much time or memory on their end to process the data. Most such APIs have parameters to request only a partial result set, such as limit, offset, or similar. Have you checked their docs in that regard?

Comment: I'd agree with @CBroe. It looks like the request is being structured properly, based on the Box.com API (https://docs.box.com/reference#view-the-comments-on-a-file). Can you provide the actual server error message being returned by Box? I notice that those response headers indicate that there's some content:  `Content-Length: 20`

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like it might be a bug with the API. Try [posting on the Box Developer forums](https://community.box.com/t5/Developer-Forum/bd-p/DeveloperForum) or [submitting a bug](https://community.box.com/t5/custom/page/page-id/BoxSearchLithiumTKB).